# Conditional Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality with Product Moment Matrices

Tags: probability, probability-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $X, Y, Z$ denote r.v.s. A possible proof for the unconditional Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality $$E(XY)^2 \leq E(X^2)E(Y^2)$$
uses the product-moment matrix $U := E(\vec{X}\vec{X}^T)$, with $\vec{X} = \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}.$ Since the product-moment matrix can be shown to be positive semi-definite, its determinant is non-negative, whence
\begin{align}
\det{U} = \det \begin{bmatrix} E(X^2) & E(XY) \\ E(XY) & E(Y^2) \end{bmatrix} = E(X^2)E(Y^2) - (E(XY))^2 \geq 0.
\end{align}
This gives the unconditional Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. I wish to now adapt this proof to prove the conditional Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:
$$E(XY|Z)^2 \leq E(X^2|Z)E(Y^2|Z),$$
for which I am having some difficulty. How should I appropriately define my product-moment matrix? If I take $\vec{X} = \begin{bmatrix} X|Z \\ Y|Z\end{bmatrix}$, I get something odd, namely,
\begin{align}
\det{U} = \det \begin{bmatrix} E(X|Z)^2 & E(X|Z*Y|Z) \\ E(X|Z*Y|Z) & E(Y|Z)^2 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Thus, how do I appropriately take into account that the r.v.'s are conditioned on $Z$ to recover the Inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conditional expectation is -- above all -- an expectation, so you can write $E(X|Z)$ or $E(XY|Z)$, but it doesn't make sense to talk about $X|Z$ or $Y|Z$ as if these are random variables that you can put in a vector $\vec{X}$ or multiply as $X|Z \star Y|Z$.

What you want to do is use the same vector $\vec{X} = [X, Y]^T$ as before and consider the conditional product-moment matrix $U=E(\vec{X}\vec{X}^T|Z)$.  It's determinant is the determinant of a matrix of conditional expectations:
$$\det[U] = \det \begin{bmatrix} E(X^2|Z) & E(XY|Z) \\ E(XY|Z) & E(Y^2|Z) \end{bmatrix}
= E(X^2|Z)E(Y^2|Z)-E(XY|Z)^2$$
and $U$ being (almost surely) positive semi-definite implies the almost sure non-negativity of the determinant giving the desired C-S inequality.

Now, $U$ is (almostly surely) positive semi-definite because *conditional* product-moment matrices are (almost surely) positive semi-definite for the same reason unconditional product-moment matrices are positive semi-definite.

To see why, recall that the *reason* (unconditional) product-moment matrices are positive semi-definite is that $\vec{X}\vec{X}^T$ is positive semi-definite pointwise in the sample space, and so:
$$\mathbf{y}^T E(\vec{X}\vec{X}^T) \mathbf{y}
= E(\mathbf{y}^T \vec{X}\vec{X}^T \mathbf{y}) \geq 0$$
with the inequality following from the expectation of a non-negative random variable being itself non-negative.

This works just as well for conditional expectations, almost surely:
$$\mathbf{y}^T E(\vec{X}\vec{X}^T|Z) \mathbf{y}
= E(\mathbf{y}^T \vec{X}\vec{X}^T \mathbf{y}|Z) \geq 0$$
since the conditional expectation of a non-negative random variable is almost surely non-negative.